# Why VS Code opens the recent folder when Ctrl+O is pressed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I press Ctrl+O inside the editor, vscode opens the *recent* folder instead of the current working folder(current file's folder)? This bug(probably) seems new, as I did not face this issue until last week. I already tried setting the following commands to a custom shortcut:

> "workbench.action.files.openFileFolder" 
> "workbench.action.files.openFolder"

VS Code version: 1.68.0 
Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

It seems that snap did not update Code package. I had to do the following to update the snap package, which fixed my problem.

> sudo snap refresh

After update, current version is: 1.68.1

[Relevant vscode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151668) that got fixed in 1.68.1